# Package for HTML, CSS quick reference

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning HTML and CSS.

I hope to learn HTML, CSS, and Java fastly.

Do any packages that could show the additional reference link for properties?

**Visual studio code:**

[image: visual studio code]

**Atom editor:**

[image]

Comment: Please note that backticks are for *code* and not for product names - please don't edit this bad formatting back in.

Comment: @ piet.t  I got your point, but backtick looks better. I am not sure which revision is acceptable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: General consensus is that this formatting is reserved for code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit/303220#303220

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Packages for Atom Editor are

1. autoclose-html
2. emmet
3. csslint
4. atom-html-preview

Packages for Visual Studio Code

1. Html CSS Support
2. HTML Snippets
3. For js Quokka.js

Comment: You seem to have recommended a number of packages which some people find useful for working with HTML, CSS and JS … but I don't think **any** of them provide the feature that the question is asking for.

Comment: I'm sure they work for lots of people. I just don't think they do what the OP is asking for.